# Clarification on how to utilize Generic list in PoSh Class property?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, oop

I don't have much background with `C#` but I want to grasp some OOP concepts in powershell. My question is, how can I utilize a Generic List as a property type in PoSh?

I tried the code below

```
enum DeviceType {
    Undefined = 0
    Compute = 1
    Rack = 32
}

class Asset {
    [string]$Brand
    [string]$Model
}

class Device : Asset {
    hidden [DeviceType]$devtype = [DeviceType]::Undefined
    [string]$Status

    [DeviceType] GetDeviceType(){
        return $this.devtype
    }
}

class ComputeServer : Device {
    hidden [DeviceType]$devtype = [DeviceType]::Compute
    [string]$ProcessorIdentifier
    [string]$Hostname
}

class Rack : Device {
    hidden [DeviceType]$devtype = [DeviceType]::Rack

    [string]$Datacenter
    [string]$Location

    # list of devices
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[Device]]$Devices

    Rack (){
    }

    [void] AddDevice([Device]$dev){
        # append a new device to the rack
        $this.Devices.Add($dev)
    }

}


$FirstRack = [Rack]::new()
$FirstRack.Status = "Operational"
$FirstRack.Datacenter = "PNW"
$FirstRack.Location = "F03R02.J10"

(0..15).ForEach({
    $ComputeServer = [ComputeServer]::new()
    $ComputeServer.Brand = "Fabrikam, Inc."       ## Inherited from Asset
    $ComputeServer.Model = "Fbk5040"              ## Inherited from Asset
    $ComputeServer.Status = "Installed"           ## Inherited from Device
    $ComputeServer.ProcessorIdentifier = "x64"    ## ComputeServer
    $ComputeServer.Hostname = ("r1s" + $_.ToString("000")) ## ComputeServer

    $FirstRack.AddDevice($ComputeServer)
  })

## gives error 
##   "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."
```

I am not able to inspect with `gm -InputObject $FirstRack.Devices -Force` but when I check the properties of the `$FirstRack` I get what is expected however I can't seem to add any devices on that property.

```
...                                                                                       
Devices        Property     System.Collections.Generic.List[Device] Devices {get;set;}
...
```

Am I using the `Collections.Generic.List` wrong? <s>or is this not possible in powershell?</s> I wanted to leverage the generic list for efficiency and be able to easily add child objects(computer devices) on the parent obj(Rack).

### EDIT 1

Okay I think I got it I just added either of the lines below and got what I expected. However, which is the correct implementation for best practices?

```
### Property declaration 1
...
$Devices = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Device]]::new()
...

### or
### Property declaration 2
...
[System.Collections.Generic.List[Device]]$Devices = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Device]]::new()
...
```

or just add something like this to the default constructor.

```
    Rack (){
        $this.Devices = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Device]'
    }
```

However, this has led me to another question, shouldn't the type `[System.Collections.Generic.List[Device]]` before my property `$Devices` take care of preparing it to accept objects of [Device] class? Do I really need to instantiate it in the constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep. You have to actually create a list otherwise `$this.Devices` is just of that type and you will receive helpful errors like `object not set to an instance of an object`. I would put it in the constructor, but that is personal preference. `New-Object` is deemed the more PowerShell way, but I would use the dotnet `::new()` more often than not. If you want to test the code later, it will be easier if you have been using PowerShell functions.

Comment: Hi @Ash, thanks for the info! I think what got me really confused here is how you just have to sort of cast `[String]` to the properties expecting a string (`[String]Datacenter`,`[String]Location`) but in the case of the Generic List, the property needs to be instantiated before it can be used..

Comment: Also, should I just omit the casting of the property to the Generic list type and just instantiate it with that type (Declaration 1) or should I make sure I cast the property to that type while equating it to the new instance of the same type(Declaration 2)? Declaration 2 seems kinda redundant to me imho, but I don't really know the best practice for it so.. 

Comment: You just need to instantiate the type, declaring the type before the variable is usually unnecessary. Just as an aside if you hadn't noticed, at the moment, a Rack can be within a rack because of the inheritance from Device too.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! 

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right! probably just means that rack is empty or unused. I just used an example from MS and made my own testing for other concepts sooo it can't be help that a rack is in a rakc.  but I do get it, must have stricter class implementations I guess! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above in the comments and as you found out yourself, you need to instantiate a list before you can add/remove members from it. If I was writing the same class in PowerShell, I would do it like this, but there are a few different ways.

```
class Rack : Device {
    hidden [DeviceType]$devtype = [DeviceType]::Rack
    [string]$Datacenter
    [string]$Location
    # You do need to tell the class the type of the property here.
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[Device]]$Devices

    Rack (){
        $this.Devices = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Device]]::new()
    }

    [void] AddDevice([Device]$dev){
        # append a new device to the rack
        $this.Devices.Add($dev)
    }
}
```